# Phonegap iOS vibration duration workaround

Tags: ios, cordova, vibration

Does anyone know how to create longer than usual vibrations for iOS in Phonegap?

The docs explicitly state:

```
navigator.notification.vibrate(2500);
IOS: Ignores the specified time and vibrates for a pre-set amount of time.
```

I would really like to know how to get around this.  It's kind of a deal-breaker.

Comment: It's highly likely that Phonegap developers have looked into this extensively and iOS simply doesn't provide an appropriate interface for this that Phonegap could use.

Comment: on iOS there is no API for vibration, right now, the cordova implementations is kind of a hack, so it isn't possible to control the duration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been struggling with this too last week. I doubt there is a way to modify the default vibration duration in Phonegap as there is no way to achieve this with the iOS API. The default vibration:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
```

lasts 4 milliseconds with one millisecond of silence. You can try to chain the same method several times but there will be always an interruption between two calls. I think there is no way to make a lengthy vibration that lasts more than 4 milliseconds :(